# JS regex match all words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Actually, I work in a language support for Atom (by git) and I use js regex but I must learn more about that.
I need to capture on groups:

```
/exe c:\dos\main.cpc /l:check
```

I need a group with `exe/`, another with `c:\dos\main.cpc`, another with `/l:` and the last with `check`.

I already tried that:

```
(exe/)([^=]+)(/l:)(.*)
```

but it did not work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape delimiter /

Your regex should be:

```
(exe\/)([^=]+)(\/l:)(.*)
```

I suggest you test your regex on this website: https://regex101.com/

It will check the syntax for you with the explanation of every elements you use in your regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one:

```
(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?:)(.*)
```

Here [is a regex test example](https://regex101.com/r/qH1lR0/1) of that.

The logic is as follows:

- first group selects all characters up until the first blank (excluded)
- any number of white space characters can follow, but are not captured
- second group selects all characters up until the next blank (excluded)
- any number of white space characters can follow, but are not captured
- third group selects all characters up until, and including, a colon
- fourth group selects all characters that follow.